# Android array of arrays with string as index

Tags: android, multidimensional-array

I'm looking for something that is surely very simple, but I don't know the best way to do it.

I could have 2 arrays of strings (that I don't know size at start), containing something like:

```
down[0]:"file1"
down[1]:"file2"
...
up[0]:"file3"
up[1]:"file4"
...
```

But I'd like them in the same array like:

```
array["down"][0]:"file1"
array["down"][1]:"file2"
array["up"][0]:"file3"
array["up"][1]:"file4"
```

And insert data with:

```
array[mykey].put(filename);
```

And loop through the data with:

```
for (String st : array["down"])
...
for (String st : array["up"])
...
```

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Hmm. I never saw array indexed with string. As I know, this is not possible. If I am wrong correct me. If you want to do such a thing you should make a method where output is int and looks like array[yourMethod("down")]. Just try to find "down" in an array and make index as an output

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a `MutableMap<String, MutableList<String>>`. In Kotlin, for example:

```
val data = mutableMapOf(
  "down" to mutableListOf("file1", "file2"),
  "up" to mutableListOf("file3", "file4")
)
```

Then you can access like:

```
data["down"].forEach { file ->
  // do something with file
}
```

Or mutate it like:

```
data["down"].add("file5")
```

For Java, you'll have to be a bit more verbose, but you can accomplish a similar result:

```
Map<String, List<String>> data = new HashMap<>();

List<String> downList = new ArrayList<>();
downList.add("file1");
downList.add("file2");
data.put("down", downList);

List<String> upList = new ArrayList<>();
upList.add("file3");
upList.add("file4");
data.put("up", upList);
```

Then:

```
for (String file : data.get("down")) {
  // do something with file
}
```

Or mutate it like:

```
data.get("down").add("file5");
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Kotlin.

Comment: Ah okay, I wasn't sure from the tags. I've updated to include a Java answer too. Same data structures apply, it's just more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Kotlin you could do

```
val data : MutableMap<String,MutableList<String>> = mutableMapOf()
data["up"] = mutableListOf()
data["down"] = mutableListOf()

// add file to up
data["up"]?.add("file1")

// get the first up
val firstUp = data["up"]?.get(0)

// map over all the ups if the are there
data["up"]?.forEach { str ->

    }
```